# Enable input box on radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code for grid view in PHP

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="radio" name="planId" id="planId1" value="1">
     <label for="planId1">Plan 1</label>
  </td>
  <td>$5 <label>per month</label></td>
  <td class="input-field col m6 subForm"><input type="number" name="monthTxt" id="monthTxt" class="planId1" min="1" maxlength="2" value="1" disabled></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
     <input type="radio" name="planId" id="planId2" value="1">
     <label for="planId1">Plan 2</label>
  </td>
  <td>$5 <label>per month</label></td>
  <td class="input-field col m6 subForm"><input type="number" name="monthTxt" id="monthTxt" class="planId2" min="1" maxlength="2" value="1" disabled></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
     <input type="radio" name="planId" id="planId3" value="1">
     <label for="planId1">Plan 3</label>
  </td>
  <td>$5 <label>per month</label></td>
  <td class="input-field col m6 subForm"><input type="number" name="monthTxt" id="monthTxt" class="planId1" min="1" maxlength="2" value="1" disabled></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

The above **'tr'** can be multiple on basic of DB data. My requirement is that whenever I click on Radio button the input text field disabled should be false.

Please let know how can I achieve this, the number of rows can be up to 10. Below is the script i have written

```
$('input:radio').change(function() {
   if($(this).is(":checked")) 
        $(this).parent().find("input:text").attr("disabled",false);
});
```

Comment: What goes wrong with the current code?

Comment: If you only want to allow one `input` to be enabled then this [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/79aq9ewu/) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thnx @NewToJS, this worked for me

Comment: @DhawalMhatre You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use `closest('tr')`
2. use class of the input when using `find()`
3. to select type of number use `"input[type=number]"`

```js
$('input:radio').change(function() {

  if ($(this).is(":checked"))
  $(this).closest('table').find("input[type=number]").not(this).attr("disabled", true);
    $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type=number]").attr("disabled", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="planId" id="planId1" value="1">
      <label for="planId1">Plan 1</label>
    </td>
    <td>$5 <label>per month</label></td>
    <td class="input-field col m6 subForm"><input type="number" name="monthTxt" id="monthTxt" class="planId1" min="1" maxlength="2" value="1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="planId" id="planId2" value="1">
      <label for="planId1">Plan 2</label>
    </td>
    <td>$5 <label>per month</label></td>
    <td class="input-field col m6 subForm"><input type="number" name="monthTxt" id="monthTxt" class="planId2" min="1" maxlength="2" value="1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="planId" id="planId3" value="1">
      <label for="planId1">Plan 3</label>
    </td>
    <td>$5 <label>per month</label></td>
    <td class="input-field col m6 subForm"><input type="number" name="monthTxt" id="monthTxt" class="planId1" min="1" maxlength="2" value="1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello,
This is working fine but the other input is not getting disabled

Comment: which other input you mean? can you update the html to show what you mean @DhawalMhatre

Comment: I have updated the HTML, the plan can be any number of row, i mean it can be Plan 1, Plan 2, Plan 3, Plan 4, Plan 5

Comment: what do you mean by `This is working fine but the other input is not getting disabled`  @DhawalMhatre

Comment: there is more than one plan if we select plan 1 than other plan input text should be disabled @guradio

Comment: @DhawalMhatre check updated answer is this what you want?

Comment: @guradio I don't see the point of having the `if` statement. When the client selects a radio button to trigger the `change` event one must be selected otherwise the event/function would never be executed. This can be done in one line `$(".planId1").not($(this).closest('tr').find(".planId1").attr("disabled", false)).attr("disabled", true);` [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/79aq9ewu/)

Answer (score 1):

So like this?

```
$('input:radio').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $(this).parent("td").nextAll().eq(1).find("input:text").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

[**nextAll**](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) here tries to traverse the next sibling elements and the input element lies inside the second sibling td so use `eq(1)`.

Comment: How do I traverse sibling elements with React.js? I just accepted your nice answer. Thank you.